# Cmake cannot find library using "link_directories"

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile

I Ubuntu, I am learning about cmake and make, and just trying a simple example. I have two directories: `src` and `build`. In `src`, I have two files: `main.cpp`, and `CMakeLists.txt`, which has (only) the following text:

```
add_executable(test main.cpp)
link_directories(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu)
target_link_libraries(test protobuf)
```

In `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, there is a shared library called `libprotobuf.so`, which I want to link against. My `main.cpp` uses functions in this library, by including the releveant header file, `#include <google/protobuf/message.h>`.

Now, in my `build` directory, I run `cmake ../src`, and then `make`. However, I then get linker errors telling me that there are undefined references to some of the functions in the protobuf library. If I do a search through all the files and subdirectories in `build`, there is not mention of anything related to protobuf.

However, if I remove the `link_directories` line in my `CMakeLists.txt` file, and instead write the full path to the library when specifying the executable, i.e. `target_link_libraries(test /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so)`, it compiles and links fine.

Why is `link_directories` not allowing cmake to find this library?

Comment: The cmake manual says about link_libraries "The command will apply only to targets created after it is called." Is the target created with the add_executable() command? Maybe you need to move the add_executable() command after the link_directories().

Comment: If I do this, I get the error `Cannot specify link libraries for target "test" which is not built by
  this project.`

Comment: Just to be sure: the order of your commands is now 1) link_directories(), 2) add_executable(), and 3) target_link_libraries()?

Comment: Yes, in that order -- and it does not add libprotobuf.so to any of the files generated by cmake

Comment: Use `find_package(Protobuf)` instead of trying to locate it directly. See http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/module/FindProtobuf.html for further information.

Comment: And if find_package() does not work for you, the next best option would be find_library(PROTOBUF protobuf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu) and then use ${PROTOBUF} in your target_link_libraries() command. Looking around the net you will see many people recommending (sometimes strongly) against using link_directories(). Even the CMake doc seems to recommend using find_library() instead.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Do not use `link_directories` like this in CMake.

This is a common beginner's mistake, as many other build environments work like this, but in CMake it's just asking for trouble. Even [the official documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/link_directories.html) specifically advises against it:

> Note that this command [`link_directories`] is rarely necessary. Library locations returned
> by `find_package()` and `find_library()` are absolute paths. Pass these
> absolute library file paths directly to the `target_link_libraries()`
> command. CMake will ensure the linker finds them.

So instead, *always pass absolute paths* to `target_link_libraries` and use [`find_library`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html) to resolve the link directory:

```
find_library(PROTOBUF_LIBRARY protobuf HINTS /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu)
target_link_libraries(test PUBLIC ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARY})
```

This has the huge benefit that you will probably get a diagnostic at CMake configure time if the expected library cannot be found, instead of a random linker error at compile time. Also, this allows the user to specify a library location via the GUI if the target machine has a non-standard directory layout.

So if it doesn't work right away, be sure to check the result of the `find_library` call and consult the official documentation to track down why it doesn't find your library as intended.

Comment: ... but, why doesn't it work? I realize it's advised against, but shouldn't it still work?

Comment: If you use pkg_check_modules to find a library you already have all the information you need and it makes sense to use pkg_check_modules.

Comment: @aardvarkk the doc says `The command will apply only to targets created after it is called. `

Comment: FYI on Windows I have found you may need to add `/*` to the hint if the library is in a subdirectory

Answer (score 96):

Make sure that your call to `link_directories` takes place **before your call** to the relevant `add_executable`.

I had mistakenly believed it only needed to be before the call to `target_link_libraries`, but that's not the case. After moving the call, the library is linked properly.

Comment: Thank you for you answer ! I have a FindSomething.cmake file that uses link_directories and in fact when using target_link_libraries on a static library to link it with library "Something" then link that static library with a binary program, the linker fails to link the libraries because link_directories is not taken in account...

Comment: This is the correct answer to the problem. The keyword here is `before your call` ...

Answer (score 9):

Make sure that the order will be link_directories, set PROJECT_LINK_LIBS, add_executable and then target_link_libraries.

Below is example to demonstarte it:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
project (Logging)
include_directories(include)
file(GLOB LOGGINGSOURCES "libsrc/*.cpp")
file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")
add_library(convertString SHARED ${LOGGINGSOURCES})
install(TARGETS convertString DESTINATION /root/Deepak/)
link_directories( /root/Deepak/ )
set(PROJECT_LINK_LIBS libconvertString.so)
add_executable(hello ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(hello ${PROJECT_LINK_LIBS} )
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's very old topic but none of proposed solutions worked for me. So I had to make my own dirty hack. I do crosscompiling with buildroot and include `toolchainfile.cmake`.

```
#...
set(LIB_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/relative/path/to/your/lib)
#...
include_directories(/path/to/library/include)
set(LIB_MYLIB ${LIB_PATH}/libmylib.so)
#...
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${APP_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
        ${LIB_MYLIB}
)
```

Hope this will help