# link ffmpeg error with cmake

Tags: ffmpeg, cmake, linker

I use cmake to create my project using ffmpeg lib, the project is simple.

```
add_executable(testffmpeg main.cpp)
link_directories( /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu )
target_link_libraries(testffmpeg libavcodec.a libavutil.a )
```

When make, there's lots of undefined reference errors (my default cxx compiler is clang by "export cxx=/usr/bin/clang++").

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.a(crystalhd.o): In function `receive_frame':(.text+0xef): undefined reference to `DtsProcOutputNoCopy'
```

but when I just use command, it's OK.

```
clang -o testffmpeg -lavutil -lavcodec main.cpp
```

while using gcc also get this error
`gcc -o testffmpeg -lavutil -lavcodec main.cpp`

so, how can I resolve this problem and where is the mistake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cmake cannot find library using "link\_directories"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31438916/cmake-cannot-find-library-using-link-directories)

Comment: I try this, while cannot solve my problem. I think the key issus it's the linker cannot resolve the function used by libavcodec.a just link the error upon, " libavcodec.a(crystalhd.o): In function `receive_frame':(.text+0xef): undefined reference to `DtsProcOutputNoCopy' "

Answer (score 0):

You need add -lcrystalhd in your linker flags.
You can use code below to find all linker flags.

```
pkg-config --libs libavformat
-L/usr/local/lib -lavformat -lXv -lX11 -lXext -ldl -lvdpau -lva -lva-x11 -lX11 -lva -lva-drm -lva -lxcb -lxcb-shm -lxcb -lxcb-xfixes -lxcb-render -lxcb-shape -lxcb -lxcb-shape -lxcb -lsndio -ljack -lasound -lSDL2 -lx264 -lcrystalhd -lm -llzma -lbz2 -lz -pthread -lavcodec -lXv -lX11 -lXext -ldl -lvdpau -lva -lva-x11 -lX11 -lva -lva-drm -lva -lxcb -lxcb-shm -lxcb -lxcb-xfixes -lxcb-render -lxcb-shape -lxcb -lxcb-shape -lxcb -lsndio -ljack -lasound -lSDL2 -lx264 -lcrystalhd -lm -llzma -lbz2 -lz -pthread -lswresample -lm -lavutil -lm
```