# Successful Makefile fails with "identical" CMake in CLion

Tags: c++, makefile, clion, cplex

I am trying to use CLion to work with IBM ILOG CPLEX 12.7.1 on my Mac OS 10.13.1 (macOS High Sierra). Here is a very simple piece of C++ code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ilcplex/ilocplex.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    IloEnv env;
    x: IloCplex cplex(env);
    std::cout << env.getVersion() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The following in my `Makefile`.

```
SYSTEM = x86-64_osx
LIBFORMAT = static_pic
CPLEXDIR = /Users/soheilmn/Applications/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1271/cplex
CONCERTDIR = /Users/soheilmn/Applications/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1271/concert
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Compiler selection 
# --------------------------------------------------------------------- 
CCC = clang++ -O0
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Compiler options 
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
CCOPT = -m64 -O -fPIC -fexceptions -DNDEBUG -DIL_STD -stdlib=libc++
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Link options and libraries
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------

CPLEXBINDIR = $(CPLEXDIR)/bin/$(BINDIST)

CPLEXLIBDIR = $(CPLEXDIR)/lib/$(SYSTEM)/$(LIBFORMAT)
CONCERTLIBDIR = $(CONCERTDIR)/lib/$(SYSTEM)/$(LIBFORMAT)

CCLNDIRS  = -L$(CPLEXLIBDIR) -L$(CONCERTLIBDIR) 
CCLNFLAGS = -lconcert -lilocplex -lcplex -lm -lpthread -ldl #-framework CoreFoundation -framework IOKit -stdlib=libc++
all:
   make main

CONCERTINCDIR = $(CONCERTDIR)/include
CPLEXINCDIR = $(CPLEXDIR)/include

CCFLAGS = $(CCOPT) -I$(CPLEXINCDIR) -I$(CONCERTINCDIR) 
# ------------------------------------------------------------
main: main.o
$(CCC) $(CCFLAGS) $(CCLNDIRS) -o main main.o $(CCLNFLAGS)
main.o: ./main.cpp
$(CCC) -c $(CCFLAGS) ./main.cpp -o main.o
```

Here is the `CMakeLists.txt`, which I have tried to create it with parameters exactly as mentioned in the `Makefile`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(cplextest)
add_executable(cplextest main.cpp)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER clang++)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}  -m64 -O -fPIC -fexceptions -DNDEBUG -DIL_STD -stdlib=libc++")
include_directories(/Users/soheilmn/Applications/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1271/cplex/include/)
include_directories(/Users/soheilmn/Applications/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1271/cplex/include/ilcplex)
include_directories(/Users/soheilmn/Applications/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1271/concert/include)
include_directories(/Users/soheilmn/Applications/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1271/concert/include/ilconcert)
find_library(lib1 NAMES libcplex.a PATHS /Users/soheilmn/Applications/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1271/cplex/lib/x86-64_osx/static_pic/)
find_library(lib2 NAMES libilocplex.a PATHS /Users/soheilmn/Applications/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1271/cplex/lib/x86-64_osx/static_pic/)
find_library(lib3 NAMES libcplexdistmip.a PATHS /Users/soheilmn/Applications/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1271/cplex/lib/x86-64_osx/static_pic/)
set (CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-lconcert -lilocplex -lcplex -lm -lpthread -ldl #-framework CoreFoundation -framework IOKit -stdlib=libc++")
target_link_libraries(cplextest PUBLIC ${lib1})
target_link_libraries(cplextest PUBLIC ${lib2})
target_link_libraries(cplextest PUBLIC ${lib3})
```

**However, while `Makefile` works flawlessly (i.e., I can successfully run my program from a terminal), CLion produces the following error messages.**

```
====================[ Build | cplextest | Debug ]===============================
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake --build /Users/soheilmn/CLionProjects/CplexTest/cmake-build-debug --target cplextest -- -j 2
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable cplextest
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "IloCplex::IloCplex(IloEnv)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "IloCplexI::getVersion() const", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [cplextest] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/cplextest.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cplextest.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [cplextest] Error 2
```

Interestingly, if I comment out the line (x) in my C++ code, I can successfully run my code from CLion. This is indeed very confusing to me, because my understanding is both procedures use `clang++` and the same libraries/header files. Any help will be highly appreciated. (Sorry for the long post in advance!)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special thanks go to "John Zwinck" for his help. I thought it makes sense to share the final CMake file that perfectly works with IBM ILOG CPLEX 12.9 under macOS 10.13.1 / CLion 2109.2.3. Here it is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(cplextest)
add_executable(cplextest main.cpp)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER clang++)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}  -m64 -O -fPIC -fexceptions -DNDEBUG -DIL_STD -stdlib=libc++")
include_directories(/Users/soheilmn/Applications/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/include/)
include_directories(/Users/soheilmn/Applications/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/include/ilcplex)
include_directories(/Users/soheilmn/Applications/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio129/concert/include)
include_directories(/Users/soheilmn/Applications/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio129/concert/include/ilconcert)
target_link_libraries(cplextest PUBLIC /Users/soheilmn/Applications/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/lib/x86-64_osx/static_pic/libcplex.a)
target_link_libraries(cplextest PUBLIC /Users/soheilmn/Applications/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/lib/x86-64_osx/static_pic/libilocplex.a)
target_link_libraries(cplextest PUBLIC /Users/soheilmn/Applications/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio129/concert/lib/x86-64_osx/static_pic/libconcert.a)
set (target_link_options "-lconcert -lilocplex -lcplex -lm -lpthread -ldl -framework CoreFoundation -framework IOKit -stdlib=libc++")
```

Answer (score 0):

`CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS` specifies flags to use when creating new shared libraries.  But your project doesn't create shared libraries, it creates an executable.  You should just pass all the library names to `target_link_libraries` like this:

```
target_link_libraries(cplextest PUBLIC "concert;cplex;ilocplex;cplexdistmip")
```

Then you *may* need to add the library search path (/Users/soheilmn/Applications/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1271/cplex/lib/x86-64_osx/static_pic/) and it should all work.  Run `make VERBOSE=1` after running `cmake` if you want to see what linker command is actually run.

To enable pthreads, see [cmake and libpthread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620918/cmake-and-libpthread)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. To make sure I fully understand you, I need to ask these questions: 1. So, you are saying I do not need to use `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS` but then what is the correct way of passing these flags to the linker? 2) I have already passed the library search path that you have mentioned by using `find_library`. Isn't that the right way of doing it and I should go with another command? 3. How/Where do I run `make VERBOSE=1' in CLion? Do I need to put that command somewhere in the `Makefile' or `CMakeLists.txt'? Many thanks for the help, again!

Comment: Use `target_link_options` to add linker options if you need any (maybe you don't).  Use `target_link_libraries` to add libraries to link.  You can pass full paths to `target_link_libraries` so there is absolutely no need to use `find_library` when you know the full absolute path already.  I don't use CLion so can't help you with the VERBOSE=1 part, but that isn't essential, just a debugging tool you can try to figure out at some point.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly now.