# Unexpected behavior by VS 2017 when compiling a CMake project that works on Linux

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, cmake, c++17

I have a CMake project that works fine on Linux with g++.

On Windows (10, Creators Update) CMake runs fine and generates relevant files.

So I opened TestProject.sln solution file and for a test run, I ran 'Local Windows Debugger' and got this error.

```
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'jsoncpp.lib'
```

This is how I've setup this project.

```
.
|-root
|  |- src
|  |- lib
|  |- bin
|  |- app
|  |- include
|  |- extras
|        |- jsoncpp
|-build
```

I'm not really sure what could be wrong here.

I have jsoncpp added as a submodule.

I did

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

and there is a jsoncpp.lib file in

```
root\lib\Debug
```

This is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.13)
project (TestProject)

set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/root/lib)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/root/lib)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/root/bin)

set(SOURCE_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/root/src)
set(INCLUDE_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/root/include)
set(EXTRAS_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/root/extras)
set(PROJECT_MAIN_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/root/app)

set(SOURCES
  ${INCLUDE_DIR}/Combinations.hpp  
  ${INCLUDE_DIR}/Lib.hpp  
  ${SOURCE_DIR}/Lib.cpp
  )

add_executable(TestProject ${PROJECT_MAIN_DIR}/Main.cpp ${SOURCES})

add_subdirectory(${EXTRAS_DIR}/jsoncpp jsoncpp)

target_link_libraries(TestProject jsoncpp)

set_target_properties(TestProject PROPERTIES
  CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
  CXX_STANDARD 17
  CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF
  )
```

This is CMake's output

```
Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.17763.0 to target Windows 10.0.17134.
The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27026.1
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27026.1
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Detecting C compile features
Detecting C compile features - done
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
JsonCpp Version: 1.8.4
Looking for C++ include clocale
Looking for C++ include clocale - found
Looking for localeconv
Looking for localeconv - found
Looking for C++ include sys/types.h
Looking for C++ include sys/types.h - found
Looking for C++ include stdint.h
Looking for C++ include stdint.h - found
Looking for C++ include stddef.h
Looking for C++ include stddef.h - found
Check size of lconv
Check size of lconv - done
Performing Test HAVE_DECIMAL_POINT
Performing Test HAVE_DECIMAL_POINT - Success
Found PythonInterp: C:/Users/USERNAME/emacs-26.1-x86_64/bin/python2.exe (found suitable version "2.7.14", minimum required is "2.6") 
Configuring done
Generating done
```

---

I'm not very familiar with Visual Studio but looking at the error, it says 'cannot open' and not 'couldn't find' so my first thought was maybe it's a permission issue.

So I booted up VS with Admin Privileges but the error continued.

I thought maybe there's some compiler issue so I used nmake.exe as a compiler (after generating nmake makefiles) but no luck there either.

I'm not sure if it's a linker issue since CMake was able to find and link jsoncpp library so I doubt CMake made a mistake building the Makefile.

I'm not sure how I should go about debugging the issue.

Comment: It seems you need to specify library location in [link_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/link_directories.html). On Linux you may have jsoncpp installed system-wide and that global library is linked.

Comment: ***first thought was maybe it's a permission issue*** No it is a location problem. You need to tell it where to look for your library. It won't look in `CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` by default.

Comment: @dewaffled I avoided using link_directories because as mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31438916/cmake-cannot-find-library-using-link-directories). Should I use something else or go with link_directories?

Comment: @dewaffled This is what I added to my CMakeLists.txt file `link_directories(${EXTRAS_DIR}/jsoncpp)`. But the error persists. I'm I missing something?

Comment: Pass absolute path to jsoncpp library starting with `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}`.

Comment: @arrowd `link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extras/jsoncpp)` where I made sure `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` is pointing to right dir (removed build dir and tried in source building by moving CMakeLists into root, changing paths). Error still persists tho :(

Comment: I probably should be `link_directories(${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY})` I highly doubt that the generated `.lib` file is in `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extras/jsoncpp`

Comment: @drescherjm That unfortunately didn't work. AFAIK `${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}` referring to an output dir without a jsoncpp.lib file. Although there's an empty Debug folder which I think should have jsoncpp.lib file.

Comment: ***Although there's an empty Debug folder which I think should have `jsoncpp.lib` file*** You will need to fix that first. Not sure how there is currently not enough information to help.

Comment: @drescherjm That was just a guess but if that's true, I think that could be the problem. There's an empty `Debug` folder in `build` dir but there's also another folder `root/lib/Debug` and there **are** `jsoncpp.exp` and `jsoncpp.lib` files. Most likely placed there by these commands `set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/root/lib)` from my CMake file. Removing them doesn't help tho

Comment: What sources are you using for jsoncpp?  The version I saw on github doesn't even create a `jsoncpp` target.  The example projects to test the library use the command: `target_link_libraries(jsoncpp_test jsoncpp_lib)`.  So unless the recipe creates a target called `jsoncpp` to link against you are trying to use some random library in the default search paths.

Comment: Where is `root/lib/Debug` versus `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/root/lib`?

Comment: Like @Fred said if the `CMakeLists.txt` for `jsoncpp` that you are using has a target named `jsoncpp_lib` using that in the target_link_libraries() should work instead of the library name. I did not follow this path because I don't know what you have in that link so I was trying to solve the linker directory problem.

Comment: One other thing if this library has an exp file the library is most likely a shared library  . You may have to adjust the paths or copy the dll to run your code.

Comment: Yes! That was the cause! I missed `_lib` part when debugging the file a couple of days ago. Apologies for taking your time, I should've been more careful. Thanks for the help tho!

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks for the advice, I'll look into it. For now the project compiled just fine and running smoothly