# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "vtkDebugLeaksManager::vtkDebugLeaksManager()", referenced from:

Tags: c++, c, vtk, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I've faced following exception when i build simple .cpp file that includes `c
pcl_visualizer.h`. Only included!

Building IDE [CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/)

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/untitled2.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable untitled2
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "vtkDebugLeaksManager::vtkDebugLeaksManager()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init.3 in main.cpp.o
  "vtkDebugLeaksManager::~vtkDebugLeaksManager()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init.3 in main.cpp.o
  "vtkObjectFactoryRegistryCleanup::vtkObjectFactoryRegistryCleanup()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init.4 in main.cpp.o
  "vtkObjectFactoryRegistryCleanup::~vtkObjectFactoryRegistryCleanup()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init.4 in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [untitled2] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled2.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled2.dir/rule] Error 2
```

**Here is my CMakeLists.txt configuration**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(untitled2)

include_directories(
        "/usr/local/include/pcl-1.9"
        "/usr/local/include/eigen3"
        "/usr/local/include/vtk/8.2.0"
        "/usr/local/include/flann/"
        "/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.71.0/include"
        "/usr/local/Cellar/vtk/8.2.0_3/include/vtk-8.2"
)

link_directories(
        "/usr/local/lib/"
)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
add_executable(untitled2 main.cpp)
```

Comment: [PCL](http://pointclouds.org) and [VTK](https://vtk.org/) libraries are located in my ```/usr/local/lib 
``` directory , So i'd configured **link_directories()** like that

Comment: https://vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Tutorials/CMakeListsFile

Comment: I'd read this documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CMakeLists.txt` doesn't need to be so verbose, fragile. Moreover, you are not linking the libraries, just specifying the paths to search for. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31438916/)

[Docs for link_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/link_directories.html) As it says in the docs, this is bad practice since `find_package` is supposed to do all this for you.

You need to specify a [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html#command:target_link_libraries) in order to find the symbols.

I use the following ([link to repo](https://github.com/kunaltyagi/pcl-cmake-minimum)):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(pcl_cmake_minimum)

find_package(PCL COMPONENTS common)

add_executable(pcl_demo main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(pcl_demo ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```